# how to pass an object to class as a parameter

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, arguments

If i have several similar classes, and i have to perform the same set of functions accessing each class, So i thought of making a generic function which takes the class and pointer as parameter. how to do that?

for example:

```
   CClass1 * pClass1 = "something";
   CClass2 * pClass2 = "something";
   CClass3 * pClass3 = "something";
```

pClass1, pClass2 and pClass3 are being used in a similar way, so i need to make a generic function passing pClass1,2,3 as parameters instead of repeating the function for three pointers..
so is ther any way in which u can send the class as well as object as a parameter??

Comment: What programming language are you using ?

Comment: C++ ,, "something" just means some values are assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question right:
The normal way in C++ to have common function for classes is to derive all classes from the very same basis class.

Beside of that, you can overload functions and operators. Then, you can apply the same (by name) function but call the function for the proper type.

Answer (score 0):

While your example code does not make sense, it seems like you are describing something which can be done using templates:

```
template<class T>
void do_something() {
    T t = "something";
}
```